# Magento - how to customize the Order PDF?

Tags: magento, pdf, customization

I need to customize the Magento Order PDF. Not the Invoice PDF. Not the Shipping PDF. Not the Credit Memo PDF. The Order PDF, the one that downloads when you are in the order View page and press print.

The reason I specify like above is that I easily found files for customizing the other three pdfs. /Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.pdf, Shipping.pdf and Creditmemo.pdf are all there, easy as pie to find and edit. Order.pdf? Nowhere to be found.

I have spent hours searching, googling, looking on the Magento wiki, and every single possible answer refers to just editing Invoice.pdf. I need to edit the straight order PDF.

Thanks for any hint or pointers on this. I feel like I'm just missing something really obvious.

EDIT: Ok, turns out this was just a plugin that I was not aware was installed on the cart that made it possible to print invoices from the order view panel in the first place.

I went into the plugin directory and the file was there.